# Magento automatically redirect me from subdirectory to main domain

Tags: magento, redirect, subdirectory

I have problem with moving Magento to another server.

Old server address:
oldserver.com/shop

New server address:
newserver.com/shop

I made backup of database and FTP files from old server and I upload files and import database to new server. After changing local.xml file with new database details Magento backend is working fine, but I have strange problem with redirection from Frontend. When I enter newserver.com/shop I can see my shop homepage in a split second and than automatically redirect me to main domain: newserver.com.

I have tried to change addresses in Admin Panel:
Base URL: {{base_url}} -> http://newdomain.com/shop/
Base Link URL: {{unsecure_base_url}} -> http://newdomain.com/shop

and the same with rest edit fields and with 'Secure' tab edits. It doesn't work, still redirect me from shop directory to main domain.
On oldserver fields {{unsecure_base_url}} were default without newserver.com/shop and it worked properly.

I tried to flush/disable all Magento caches after installation and still not works.

I have tried to install clean Magento in newdomain.com directory and all is fine, it doesn't redirect me to main domain. Any ideas what is going on? :)

My .htaccess file is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /magento/  (I have tried to change it to /shop/ and uncomment and still redirect me)
#RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: looks like something in the code does the redirect... do a grep...

Answer (score 1):

Check secure and unsecure magento path in db table core_config_data.

Clean

```
/var/cache/* 
/var/session/* 
/var/log/*
```

and also clean the cache of your browser.

Finally check if RewriteBase in .htaccess in root is set.

Comment: I have checked core_config_data table and paths are OK- the same as in backend panel. I have cleaned above catalogs and still the same. In root I haven't got .htaccess file. When I install clean installation of Magento and it works fine. Probably I will make fresh install, copy theme and configure it manually, or maybe do you have better idea? There is the same problem on my localhost and shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately today i had the same problem with a new magento project. :-)
Please check each line in table core_config_date. Web secure and unsecure path can appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no .htaccess in the root of your magento installation you should add it.
You don't need to do a new clean install.

Answer (score 0):

I asked company which created this theme at oldserver.com/shop to moving Magento. Now it's working at new server, but new server is a bit slow, so when I enter newdomain.com/shop I can see title of the page: 404, and than Magento redirect automaticaly to one of categories which is 'home' category. I think that my problem was because before Magento redirect to main domain when don't find homepage and now they set redirection of one of category. I hope that it can be useful for anybody in future.